# Android PDF to Bitmap rendering

Tags: android, pdf

I have PDF files that contains 1 single icon.
I need to render this icons in GridView.

On Android 5 I'm using PdfRenderer system class and it works amazing:
[image]

On Android 4, I'm using "Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library".
https://github.com/jblough/Android-Pdf-Viewer-Library
It works, but the quality is poor:
[image]

Can you please suggest any alternatives for rendering PDF as Bitmap?
Or maybe there is a way to increase quality of rendering for that library?
Here is my code:

```
private static Bitmap renderToBitmap(Context context, InputStream inStream) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        byte[] decode = IOUtils.toByteArray(inStream);
        ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(decode);
        PDFPage mPdfPage = new PDFFile(buf).getPage(0, true);
        float width = mPdfPage.getWidth();
        float height = mPdfPage.getHeight();
        bitmap = mPdfPage.getImage((int) (width), (int) (height), null, true,
                true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            inStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your PDF might be using some transparency objects. Generally when you see areas of an image that are black this is the case. Transparency is complex so it is not fully supported in a lot of hobbie PDF libraries. I presume in Android 5 it is using PDFium where it is supported.